# Android: Datepicker Dialog causes crash?

Tags: android, datepicker

I made an android app that sends date to mysql. It was successful, then I tried making a tab widget. Both tabs contain the same code but are two different classes now after doing this the date picker dialog started to crash when activated.

What is the causes to this?

logcat report

```
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@533459e0 is not valid; is your activity running?
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at com.example.androidtablayout.VacLeave$2.onClick(VacLeave.java:129)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-03 16:32:15.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1445):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code for datepicker 
VacLeave.java

```
 public class VacLeave extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btnCreateProduct;
    ListView listView;
String[] trans;

// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
JSONArray jsonarray;

EditText inputName;
String username;
EditText inputStart;
EditText inputEnd;
Button btnLogout;
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

private String url = "http://10.0.3.2/sunshine-ems/vac.php";


private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.leave);

    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputStart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputStart);
    inputEnd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEnd);
    btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);





    inputStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view)


        {
            int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(VacLeave.this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

                        c.set(year, month, day);
                        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(c.getTime());
                        inputStart.setText(date);

                        int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                         }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            if(!((Activity) VacLeave.this).isFinishing())
            {
                dpd.show();
            }
        }
    });

    inputEnd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(VacLeave.this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

                        c.set(year, month, day);
                        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(c.getTime());
                        inputEnd.setText(date);

                        int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            if(!((Activity) VacLeave.this).isFinishing())
            {
                dpd.show();
            }
        }
    });
    // CHECK TO LOGIN SESSION
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    session.checkLogin();
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);;
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Launching All products Activity
                    session.logoutUser();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });

    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(this);
}


private class Submit extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(VacLeave.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Processing Leave request");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        int success;
        Spinner mySpinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        username = session.getUsername();

        List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        String reason = inputName.getText().toString();
        String start = inputStart.getText().toString();
        String end = inputEnd.getText().toString();
        String status ="pending";
        String leavetype="vacation";
        //String leavetype = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        try {

            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reason", reason));
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start", start));
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("end", end));
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("leavetype", leavetype));
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", status));
            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST",
                    params1);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Payment attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(VacLeave.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Logout button click event
 * */
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btnCreateProduct:
        if ( checkValidation () )
            new Submit().execute();
        else
            Toast.makeText(VacLeave.this, "Required field(s)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

}
private boolean checkValidation() {
    boolean ret = true;

    if (!Validation.hasText(inputName)) ret = false;
    if (!Validation.hasText(inputStart)) ret = false;
    if (!Validation.hasText(inputEnd)) ret = false;



    return ret;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It happens when the activity which is calling the dialog was finishing for some reason or another when it tried to show a dialog.

This is what you can do

Replace

```
dpd.show();
```

with

```
if(!((Activity) SickLeave.this).isFinishing())
{
    dpd.show();
}
```

Comment: should I put the if statement after the "public void onClick(View view)"??

Comment: Put it where `dpd.show();` is. This statement should be in the if statement I wrote.

Comment: Im sorry but it still crashes :(

Comment: Can you update you code? Let me check where you have used it.

Comment: Done. What I do not understand is that this was working perfectly well. When I duplicated it within the same project that caused it

Comment: Is this code in `SickLeave` activity? I think its in `VacLeave`. If this code is in any fragment then replace `SickLeave.this` with `getActivity()` and if its in any other activity use that activity name. Seem like a copy paste error.

Comment: Both activity crashes

Comment: Where is this code? which activity? Or is it in a fragment? Please post the class where this code is.

Comment: Thank you very much I have posted both codes. This is not fragment

Comment: I apologize.I misread your comment. I have posted the entire class code thank you

Comment: you are opening the dialog picker on edit text click. But I dont think that could be the cause. Take backup of your class and use this code http://pastebin.com/EHCn1zSH Try clicking on `inputStart` only. Just for testing don't do any thing except clicking the `inputStart` field. Lets see how it behaves.